# How do you limit a Facebook app to a small number of people during testing?

Tags: facebook

I know about test accounts, but during beta I'd like to allow access only to my friends, and then later friends-of-friends, and then only eventually Kevin Bacon and his friends.

That would probably suck, wouldn't it? The app would be listed (is there a way to prevent listing?) and someone I don't know might try it and get a "sorry, this is in development message." I imagine they'd be irritated and not come back.

From what I've read, only a few apps take off, but when they take off, they REALLY take off. Do developers just release these things fully baked?

Anyone start out with OpenSocial or other smaller-than-Facebook networks?

Any ideas for a soft, gradual, restricted roll-out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apps are only listed in the App Directory if you *submit them* and they are *accepted*. There's no issue about preventing listing, it's something you have to apply for.

As for restricting users, you can accomplish it with a script in the application that checks whether the currently logged-in user is within your restricted user set. For example, if you only want friends of yourself, check whether the current user is friends with your user id. If not, simply display an error/message page or redirect them to the Facebook home page (or wherever). Add this check to the rest of the start-up logic run each page (such as connecting to your DB and authenticating with Facebook).

What I have done in some cases is keep a database table with the user id's of users who are allowed access, essentially a "whitelist". If the user isn't in the table, redirect them.

Answer (score 10):

Once you've set up your application, there is a setting in the Developer application control panel for your app:  Your app -> Advanced -> Sandbox Mode.

Sandbox mode lets you restrict access to only those people listed as developers (under the Basic section).

In terms of expanding the app, Facebook doesn't provide much more flexibility that the Sandbox mode.  Unfortunately, adding everyone as Developers of the app doesn't work very well for a beta, as people can access the application control panel once they are a developer.  I ended up putting a whitelist of Facebook Ids into the front controller of my application for a previous beta, and it worked fairly well.